# Hook to replace a page's content with a string contained in a variable in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress plugin where I have to render some specific content when appropriated instead of pages.

Here is the current situation (all files are in the root folder of the plugin):

my-template.php

```
<?php
echo "hi world";
```

my-plugins-main-php-file.php

```
//...logic to determine if the content of the page has to be rendered...
function load_template(){
    return __DIR__."/my-template.php";
}
add_action('template_include', 'load_template');
```

And here is the desired result:

my-plugins-main-php-file.php

```
//...logic to determine if the content of the page has to be rendered...
add_action('string_include_or_some_other_hook',"hi world");
```

Is there a hook or some other method I can use to render some wordpress content directly from a string?

Thanks!

Comment: The filter `the_content` may work  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content  `The "the_content" filter is used to filter the content of the post after it is retrieved from the database and before it is printed to the screen`  in your filter you could use GET variable to switch your content etc.

Comment: Otherwise, are these like external PHP html pages?  if so you could make a shortcode then all you have to do is add a page in WP put the shortcode in.  It still gives you some options of WP such as adding the page to the menu etc.  With a minimal amount of work. create a page, paste the shortcode, save.

Comment: Please clarify your question. "render some wordpress content directly from a string?" What do you mean? Wordpress renders everything using template php files. You redirect Wordpress to output the template of your choice (as you have done), and then whatever string you want to print, you echo out inside that template. I dont see the problem?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the idea is to avoid having to create a page manually. I'm testing your solution right now, thanks!

Comment: @Mikepote what do you do if you want to include variables in your template? That could solve my problem. As regarding the title, I get what you are saying, I'm trying to figure out a better one.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I just tested your solution. It worked, with a little more work on it. I'm gonna post my solution

Comment: Kool, glad it helped you.

Comment: @CharlesBrocchiero If you need variables, you can just use them inside your `my-template.php` file. A template file is just plain PHP, you can load a string from disk, get it from a global variable from another part of your code, look up a database and display that. Literally anything is possible :) But ArtisticPhoenix's way will also work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to my question, thanks to @ArtisticPhoenix:

my-plugins-main-php-file.php

```
//...logic to determine if the content of the page has to be rendered...
function load_template(){
    return __DIR__."/my-template.php";
}
add_action('template_include', 'load_template');

$string = "hi world!";
add_filter('the_content', function() use ($string){
    return $string;
});
```

my-template.php

```
<?php
the_content();
```